# 4 sum challenge

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-2.x

> **Problem**
>
> Given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many tuples
>   (i, j, k, l) there are such that A[i] + B[j] + C[k] + D[l] is zero.
>
> To make problem a bit easier, all A, B, C, D have same length of N
>   where \$0 \le N \le 500\$. All integers are in the range of \$-2^{28}\$ to \$2^{28} - 1\$
>   and the result is guaranteed to be at most \$2^{31} - 1\$.
>
> **Example**:
>
> *Input*:
>
> ```
> A = [ 1, 2]
> B = [-2,-1]
> C = [-1, 2]
> D = [ 0, 2]
> ```
>
> *Output*:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> *Explanation*:
>
> The two tuples are:
>
> 1. (0, 0, 0, 1) -> A[0] + B[0] + C[0] + D[1] = 1 + (-2) + (-1) + 2 = 0
> 2. (1, 1, 0, 0) -> A[1] + B[1] + C[0] + D[0] = 2 + (-1) + (-1) + 0 = 0

I'm wondering if there are any ideas to have a solution less than \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def build_sum_map(list1, list2, sum_map):
    for index_i, i in enumerate(list1):
        if i > 0 and list1[index_i] == list1[index_i-1]:
            continue
        for index_j, j in enumerate(list2):
            if j > 0 and list2[index_j] == list2[index_j-1]:
                continue
            sum_map[i+j].append((i,j))

def combine_sum(sum_map1, sum_map2, result):
    for k,v in sum_map1.items():
        if -k in sum_map2:
            for i in v:
                for j in sum_map2[-k]:
                    result.append(i+j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sum_map1 = defaultdict(list)
    sum_map2 = defaultdict(list)
    build_sum_map([1, 2], [-2,-1], sum_map1)
    build_sum_map([-1, 2], [ 0, 2], sum_map2)
    result = []
    combine_sum(sum_map1, sum_map2, result)
    print result
```

Comment: This algorithm is not n^2 since you loop through sum_map2. Since you only need the count of tuples, you should modify your map to need counts as well.

Comment: Thanks  Raziman,  I just did re-calculate based on your comments, for your comments -- "This algorithm is not n^2 since you loop through sum_map2", if you mean in method `combine_sum`, outer loop I loop through `sum_map1`, and in the inner loop, I loop through `sum_map2`, suppose in one of the 4 lists, there are `1/4 * n` elements, then suppose `sum_map1` has `n^2` elements (# of combination of sum), and `sum_map2` has `n^2` elements, then you think the total time complexity is `n^4`? Please correct me if my calculation is wrong.

Comment: For your comments -- "Since you only need the count of tuples, you should modify your map to need counts as well.", totally agree. I will post a new version of code later after above question is answered. Raziman. :)

Comment: Yes, I believe the complexity would be n^4, easily seen when all elements in all lists are equal.

Comment: @RazimanT.V., thanks for the advice, I have added a new post to fix the issue you mentioned here (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153271/4-sum-challenge-part-2), appreciate and looking forward to your advice. :)

Comment: This question is unanswered but got a follow-up question posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153271/4-sum-challenge-part-2). This question will be closed as a duplicate [per site policy](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5072/52915).